# Barchart faceting by class in ggplot2, while preserving the label-structure of the y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am utilizing the ggplot2 package in R to plot functional categories by their count. As seen in the plot below, the categories have been ordered by protein count and also by what class they fall into.

[image]

Here is a portion of the dataset I am working with:

```
GO_Category                              protein_count  Class
aromatic amino acid family metabolic process        24  Amino acid metabolism
glutamine family amino acid metabolic process       14  Amino acid metabolism
aspartate family amino acid metabolic process       10  Amino acid metabolism
glutamine family amino acid biosynthetic process    9   Amino acid metabolism
branched-chain amino acid metabolic process         8   Amino acid metabolism
peptidyl-lysine modification to hypusine            4   Amino acid metabolism
ornithine metabolic process                         3   Amino acid metabolism
single-organism carbohydrate metabolic process      125 Carbohydrate metabolism
carbohydrate biosynthetic process                   55  Carbohydrate metabolism
pentose metabolic process                           7   Carbohydrate metabolism
mannose metabolic process                           3   Carbohydrate metabolism
organelle organization                              101 Cellular components
ribonucleoprotein complex biogenesis                41  Cellular components
plastid organization                                35  Cellular components
```

Here is an code I am using in R:

```
nameorder <- df$GO_Category[order(df$Class, df$protein_count)]
df$GO_Category <- factor(df$GO_Category, levels=nameorder)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=GO_Category, y=protein_count, fill=GO_Category)) + 
  geom_bar(color="black", stat="identity", width=0.5, position=position_dodge(.5)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) + 
  ylab("Protein Association Count") + xlab("Gene Ontology Category") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="#999999")) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = protein_count), size = 3, hjust = -0.5)
```

What I would like to do is facet the groups by their Class identifier, but maintaining the structure of the y-axis. My attempts at this have produced some rather ugly plots that seem to repeat the labels on the y-axis for each facet.

[image]

Comment: these classes, you downloaded they where?

Answer (score 1):

facet_wrap has an argument scales which you can use. scales='free_y' (or possibly 'free_x' if you did a coord_flip() to make this plot) should do the trick - http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html

'Free' in the context of factor variables means that values which aren't observed within the category aren't shown on the axis.

Use this in conjunction with space = 'free_x'/'free_y' to make the scale the same across all facets (so that categories with fewer or more categories aren't shrunken/enlarged.

edit: space isn't implemented for facet_wrap yet, but you may be able to achieve what you want with facet_grid

Comment: Ok, that explains the scaling better for me. I had tried something along those lines by adding: + facet_wrap(Class ~ ., scales = "free_x", space="free_x"). But this gives me the following error: Error in facet_wrap(Class ~ ., scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") : 
  unused argument (space = "free_x")

Comment: I just remembered that I think the space parameter is only implemented for facet_grid. I think usually you can get facet_grid to function similarly to facet_wrap though (not in front of R right now to try it out).